# Obtain the elasticsearch client using RestClient for DELETE and SCROLLAPI

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch to save data coming from twitter.
At this point I'm having difficulty deleting data from index and using the Scroll API because after reading about ways to do that, everyone uses the Client and I'm using RestClient.

What I am using:

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(
 new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
 new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();
```

What I found:

For Delete:

```
DeleteIndexResponse deleteResponse = client.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest("your-index")).actionGet()
```

For Scroll:

```
SearchResponse scrollResp = client.prepareSearch(test)
        .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
        .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
        .setQuery(qb)
        .setSize(100).get();
```

How do I get the client using RestClient?
Will I have to create Java High Level REST Client?
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

elasticsearch that you are using itself will have a client or somebody from open community would have provided for example https://atom.io/packages/elasticsearch-client or https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html. If you need more functionalities then you have to provide your own implementation by extend them.

Comment: Using the Transport Client [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html) it would be possible to do what I am looking for, but as it will be discontinued / deprecated, I used RestClient [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html).Is it possible to use both?

Comment: Using both might clutter the code and create issues in maintainability.